# Как найти значение во вложенных списках python и, если его там нет, то дописать

Tags: python, list

Как найти значение во вложенных списках python и, если его там нет, то дописать?

```
[['sama', 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, nan, nan, 33.0, nan, '14'], ['samo', 12, 11, 12, 11, 12, 11, nan, 14.0, nan, nan, '14'], ['sami', 13, 11, 13, 11, 13, 11, 12.0, nan, nan, 33.0, '14'], ['sam', 14, 11, 14, 11, 14, 11, nan, nan, nan, nan, '14']]
```

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    for j in range(len(list[i])):
        if i == "14":
            continue
        if i != "13":
            list[i].append("13")
```

Список загружаю через pandas из excel, а может проще не загружать а сразу просмотреть строки в excel и если значения нет дописать в конце строки?

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, **что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: идете по списку через `for` и если значение итерируемое идете по нему опять же через `for` и так рекурсивно

Comment: О каком значении речь?

Comment: for i in range(len(list)):
    for j in range(len(list[i])):
        if i == "14":
            continue
    if i != "13":
     list[i].append("13")

Comment: Например значение 13

Comment: Zhihar: вот например пробую вот этим кодом не выходит подставляет во все списки 14

Comment: for i in range(len(list)):
    for j in range(len(list[i])):
        if i == "14":
            continue
    if i != "14":
     list[i].append("14")

Comment: почему вы не делаете это прямо в pandas? зачем еще в список выгружать?

Comment: сформулируйте правильно вопрос. я там понимаю, что вам нужно выяснить, есть ли во вложенном списке строка "13", если есть, ничего не делать, если нет - добавить в список?

Comment: Все списки нужно проверить есть ли там нужная цифра (например 13 или любая другая или текущая дата) если ее там нет то дописать в конкретный список. Каждый список это отдельная строка в excel таблице